# How to translate a dynamic title attribute

Tags: localization, internationalization, plone

I have this kind of translation to make :

```html
<a tal:attributes="href troncon/url; 
                   title string:Cette etape fait partie du troncon ${troncon/nom}"
   tal:content="troncon/nom">Canal du centre</a>
```

You see that I have a dynamic title attribute that I want to be translatable.

I've tried like this :

```html
<a tal:attributes="href troncon/url; 
                   title string:Cette etape fait partie du troncon ${troncon/nom}"
   tal:content="troncon/nom" 
   i18n:attributes="title">Canal du centre</a>
```

And like this :

```html
<a tal:attributes="href troncon/url; 
                   title string:Cette etape fait partie du troncon ${troncon/nom}"
   tal:content="troncon/nom" 
   i18n:attributes="title" 
   title="Cette etape fait partie du troncon ${nom}">Canal du centre</a>
```

But this doesn't work (of course).

Any ideas ?

Comment: did not try this but it could work:

your view could provide a method/property that returns the title as messageid (eg view.mytitle)

in the template the following should be sufficient:
tal:attribute="title view/mytitle" i18n:attributes="title"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the `tal:attributes` call is passed literally to the translation machinery. `i18n:attributes` matches it's keys against what `tal:attributes` generates, and if there is a match, the original attribute on the element is ignored (see this [I18N article on the Zope 3 wiki](http://wiki.zope.org/zope3/ZPTInternationalizationSupport).

This means that the *result* of "Cette etape fait partie du troncon ${troncon/nom}" will be looked up for translation, requiring you to provide translations for each variation of the sentence that can be made with all possible values of `troncon/nom`.

To get support for proper placeholders in this string you are better off creating a message id in the code that generates the `troncon` structure and translate it there, presumably in your view. You need:

- A message id with the placeholder
- Attach the `nom` value to the message id
- Translate this message to the currently selected language
- Include the result in your `troncon` structure

I generally do this is one step:

```
from zope.i18n import translate
from zope.i18nmessageid import MessageFactory

_ = MessageFactory('yourdomain')

troncon = dict(
    ...
    nom=nom,
    nomtitre=translate(
        _(u'troncon_nomtitre', default=u'Cette etape fait partie du troncon ${nom}',
            mapping=dict(nom=nom)),
        context=self.request)
)
```

Do note that you need a request for the translation function to pick the correct language.

Answer (score 0):

You can always force the translation on `context.translate()`:

```
 tal:attributes="foobar python:context.translate(string, domain='translationdomain')"
```

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/i18n/internationalisation.html#manually-translated-message-ids

However, this might be against all best practices.

Comment: The biggest downside to this approach is that the string won't get picked up as a message id by i18ndude and other tools for finding translatable strings. Better to use what fRiSi described in the comment on the question, I think.